# DataTrigger in code

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I've tried to get this working, based on the answer I received to *[Convert some XAML to C# using WPF][1]*, but I'm missing something.

I've pasted a sample of my code below.

```
// uGrid = UniformGrid
uGrid.Columns=2;
// test - setup first ellipse
Ellipse ellipse1 = new Ellipse() { Width=25, Height=25, Fill=Brushes.DodgerBlue, Margin= new Thickness(3), Opacity=0 };
uGrid.Children.Add(ellipse1);
var fadeEllipse1 = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 0, To = 1, Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.secondsToFade), FillBehavior=FillBehavior.Stop };
Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeEllipse1, ellipse1);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeEllipse1, new PropertyPath(Ellipse.OpacityProperty));
Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();

storyBoard.Children.Add(fadeEllipse1);
storyBoard.RepeatBehavior=RepeatBehavior.Forever;

// test - setup 2nd ellipse using example below
Ellipse ellipse2 = new Ellipse() { Width=25, Height=25, Fill=Brushes.DodgerBlue, Margin= new Thickness(3), Opacity=0 };
uGrid.Children.Add(ellipse2);

var style = new Style(typeof(Ellipse));
var trigger = new DataTrigger();
trigger.Binding = new Binding("Opacity") { ElementName = "ellipse1" };
trigger.Value = 1;

Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

var fadeEllipse2 = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 0, To = 1, Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.secondsToFade), FillBehavior=FillBehavior.Stop };
Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeEllipse2, ellipse2);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeEllipse2, new PropertyPath(Ellipse.OpacityProperty));
Storyboard.SetTargetName(fadeEllipse2, ellipse2.Name);
sb.Children.Add(fadeEllipse2);
sb.RepeatBehavior=RepeatBehavior.Forever;

trigger.EnterActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sb });
style.Triggers.Add(trigger);

storyBoard.Begin();
```

Comment: Sorry. The 2nd storyboard attached to ellipse2 never triggers when ellipse1 opacity reaches 1, I tried different values for the trigger.value - .7 , .5 - I'm setting something up wrong and it's not triggering.

Comment: I see i got two thumbs down, if someone would let me know what I did it would be more constructive, so I'd know what to avoid in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code:

1. You're creating a style, but you don't use it anywhere, you're missing the line

   ```
   ellipse2.Style = style;
   ```
2. You're trying to bind to an element with the name `ellipse1`, but it does not exist (having variable with that name is not the same thing). But even if you set the `Name` of `ellipse1`, it wouldn't work. You have to declare the name in XAML for that. In code-behind, you can use `Source` and bind to the other ellipse directly, without using names (which would be a better solution anyway, even if using names worked):

   ```
   trigger.Binding = new Binding("Opacity") { Source = ellipse1 };
   ```
3. You're comparing whether two doubles have *exactly the same value*. That's almost always a bad idea, and in this case especially. The `Opacity` of `ellispse1` doesn't change continuously, it changes by jumping. By default, the value changes at most 60 times per second (at least it was that way when I tested it, I didn't find this value documented anywhere). So, the `Opacity` might start at exactly 0, stay that way for 1/60 s and then jump to 1/60. Because of this, comparing for exact value is even less reliable than when comparing doubles for equality normally (which is not reliable to start with). Using a converter that checks, whether the opacity is greater than `0.99` seems to work for me, but it's still not reliable: if the dispatcher is busy, the opacity can jump, say, from 0.85 straight to 0.12.

   ```
   public class GreaterThanConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       public object Convert(
           dynamic value, Type targetType, dynamic parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           return value > parameter;
       }

       public object ConvertBack(
           object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           throw new NotSupportedException();
       }
   }
   ```

   ```
   trigger.Binding = new Binding("Opacity")
                       {
                           Source = ellipse1,
                           Converter = new GreaterThanConverter(),
                           ConverterParameter = 0.99
                       };
   trigger.Value = true;
   ```
4. Apparently

   > A Storyboard tree in a Style cannot specify a TargetName. Remove TargetName.

   So delete the following like, it's not useful anyway.

   ```
   Storyboard.SetTargetName(fadeEllipse2, ellipse2.Name);
   ```